# OpenModelica solver reaches maximal number of iteration but not able to find root

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, systemmodeler

I am trying to simulate a 1D system of 3 sliding bodies as [I have explained here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/348240/modeling-static-coulomb-friction-in-a-multibody-system/348254#348254):

[image]

and here is the code I have implemented:

```
model friction
  //constants
  parameter Real muk = 0.2;
  parameter Real mus = 0.3;
  parameter Real m1 = 1.0;
  parameter Real m2 = 2.0;
  parameter Real m3 = 3.0;
  parameter Real Fn12 = 3.0;
  parameter Real Fn23 = 2.0;
  parameter Real absTol = 0.1;
  //variables
  Real X1, X2, X3, V1, V2, V3, A1, A2, A3, F1, F2, F3, Ff12, Ff23, Fs12, Fs23;

initial equation
  X1 = 0;
  X2 = 0;
  X3 = 0;
  V1 = 0;
  V2 = 0;
  V3 = 0;
equation
  F1 = 2 * sin(5 * time);
  F2 = 2 * sin(7 * time);
  F3 = 3 * sin(11 * time);
  V1 = der(X1);
  V2 = der(X2);
  V3 = der(X3);
  A1 = der(V1);
  A2 = der(V2);
  A3 = der(V3);
  m1 * A1 = F1 - Ff12;
  m2 * A2 = F2 + Ff12 - Ff23;
  m3 * A3 = F3 + Ff23;
  Fs12 = (m2 * F1 - m1 * (F2-Ff23)) / (m1 + m2);
  Fs23 = (m3 * (F2 + Ff12) - m2 * F3) / (m2 + m3);

  if abs(V1 - V2) < absTol and abs(Fs12) < mus * Fn12 then
    Ff12 = Fs12;
  else
    Ff12 = muk * Fn12 * sign(V1 - V2);
  end if;

  if abs(V3 - V2) < absTol and abs(Fs23) < mus * Fn23 then
    Ff23 = Fs23;
  else
    Ff23 = muk * Fn23 * sign(V2 - V3);
  end if;


end friction;
```

Wolfram SystemModeler is able to run the simulation till t=6sec, but the results are not what I expect as [I have explained here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28227/moedlica-and-simulink-yield-completely-different-results?noredirect=1#comment50956_28227). And when I use OpenModelica to solve the simulation I get the error below:

> C:/Users/foo/AppData/Local/Temp/OpenModelica/OMEdit/friction.exe -port=64457 -logFormat=xmltcp -override=startTime=0,stopTime=10,stepSize=0.02,tolerance=1e-6,solver=dassl,outputFormat=mat,variableFilter=.* -r=friction_res.mat -jacobian=coloredNumerical -w -lv=LOG_STATS
>   Warning: maximal number of iteration reached but no root found
>   Warning: maximal number of iteration reached but no root found
>   Error solving nonlinear system 42 at time 0.2
>   Error solving nonlinear system 42 at time 0.2
>   nonlinear system 42 fails: at t=0.2
>   Solving non-linear system 42 failed at time=0.2.
>   For more information please use -lv LOG_NLS.
>   Simulation process failed. Exited with code -1.

[image]

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to write your own Friction model.

In Modelica the normal way is to use s-parameterization by e.g. inheriting from: Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Interfaces.PartialFriction (or using an existing model doing that).

It's documentation is online at:
http://doc.modelica.org/help/Modelica_Mechanics_Rotational_UsersGuide.html#Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.UsersGuide.ModelingOfFriction

Specifically you have Fs12 and Fs23 that are maximum friction force for adherence, which works if the are constant  - but here they depend on Ff12 and Ff23 - and they in turn depend on Fs12 and Fs23; which does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So how should I change the code? I would appreciate if you could include the correct modelica code.

Answer (score 2):

For dry friction modeling I can recommend https://github.com/dzimmer/ZimmersModelicaTutorial/blob/master/Tutorial2015/BaseComponents/Friction/IdealDryFriction.mo which reuses Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Interfaces.PartialFriction in a simple and clean way.

Comment: Thanks. could you be so kind to let me know which part of my code is wrong and how I can fix it?